# Can I bring alcohol free beer (<0.5% ABV) into Louisiana from The Netherlands?

Tags: usa, air-travel, netherlands, alcohol, louisiana

I am trying to figure out if I can take non alcoholic beer with me to my family in Louisiana. I could only find [this Louisiana State Legislature article](http://legis.la.gov/Legis/law.aspx?d=78725) which mentions:

> "Alcoholic beverage" means beer, distilled spirits, and wine containing one-half of one percent or more of alcohol by volume.

And the beer I want to bring is 0.3% ABV. It's labeled non-alcoholic here and that's clearly readable and understandable from the label.

Comment: Sounds like you identified it's not an alcoholic beverage. Probably the same rules apply as for Coca-Cola, then. If in doubt, declare it to customs and they will tell you whether it's allowed, and if it's not allowed you will have to throw it out.

Comment: How old are you, and how much do you plan to bring?

Comment: Also, where will you enter the United States (your "Port of Entry")?

Comment: Also, are you a visitor or a returning resident?

Comment: I was about to say, "Can you buy it locally instead?", but then I remembered that Fosters in the US is brewed under license in the US and not in Australia, so technically it is not the same product. (not that I am advocating drinking Fosters)

Comment: Oops, took that to be a link to the Netherlands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the possible issues with bringing (potentially) alcoholic beverages into the US from abroad:

- Export from the Netherlands: I don't believe there would be an issue in this case.
- Security: if you want to keep them in your hand luggage, you won't be allowed to have any container larger than 100 ml, and all containers holding liquids must fit into a 1l bag. So most probably not in hand luggage. For checked bags, there's no limitation on volume for beverages with low alcohol content like those. Don't forget to pack all containers very well, you don't want beer spilling in your bags.
- Customs on entry into the US: Alcoholic beverages generally have a 1l duty free allowance. If they consider it to be an alcoholic beverage, then you must declare it if you have more than 1l. There may be stricter rules per state (which will depend on the port of entry). If it's not an alcoholic beverage, then those are goods you intend to leave in the US, so you should declare their value. If you remain under $100 (visitor) or $800 (returning resident), no taxes.
- Agricultural inspection on entry into the US (performed by customs): since this is may be classified as a form of food, you should declare it, but there should be no issue with that.
- Other restrictions in any state you go through on your way: depends on the state.
- If you are under 21: no, no, no.

Basically, just declare it on form 6059B if you are given one or on the kiosks if they ask the question. If any CBP officer asks, just say you have (X quantity of) non-alcoholic beer. They should wave you away pretty fast.